# How to calculate $14^{2017^{2017}} \mod 60$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modules, congruences

$14^{2017^{2017}} \mod 60$

So, I know that I should begin with decomposing $60$ to the prime factors, which are: $ 3, 2^2, 5$, now I should calculate $14^{2017^{2017}} mod$ all three of these prime factors.

My question is, what is the easiest way of calculating $14^{2017^{2017}} \mod 3$?

Comment: Modulo $3$ and $5$ , we get $(-1)$ to the power of an odd number, hence $-1$. Modulo $4$, we obviously get $0$. Now apply the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Hint: Use Euler's theorem $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 $ (mod $n$) whenever $a$ is an integer relatively prime to $n$. A special case ( when $n$ is prime) is  Fermat's (Little) Theorem.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson While generally a viable approach, the Chinese remainder theorem is much quicker in this specific case. I usually use CRT before applying Euler's theorem anyways; it lets me work with much smaller totients.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Which is false, because $60$ and $14$ are not coprime. Also, the above comment by Peter is shorter, and basically answers the problem, albeit perhaps not thoroughly enough to count as a full answer.

Comment: @Arthur: Sorry, yes, I did not read carefully enough

Answer (score 6):

By Euler's Theorem, $14^{\phi(60)}\equiv 1\mod 60$.  We can calculate, using the product formula for the $\phi$ function, that $\phi(60)=16$.  So we need to find $2017^{2017}\mod 16$.  Now we repeat: $2017\equiv 1\mod 16$, so 
$$2017^{2017}\equiv 1^{2017}\equiv 1\mod 16$$
Then we have
$$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 14^{k(16)+1}\equiv 1\cdot 14\equiv 14\mod 60$$

Edit: As noted by multiple people in the comments, we *cannot* use Euler's Theorem because $14$ and $60$ are not coprime.  One resolution is factor $14=2\cdot 7$, and then apply Euler's Theorem to the second factor.  As before, $2017\equiv 1\mod 16$ and we get

$$14^{2017^{2017}}=2^{2017^{2017}}7^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^{2017^{2017}}\cdot 7 \mod 60$$

Now we have to find $2^{2017^{2017}}\mod 60$.  Note that $2^2\equiv 4\mod 60$ and $2^6=64\equiv 4\mod 60$. So computing $2^k\mod 60$ just amounts to computing the residue of $k \mod 4$ for $k\geq 2$.  Well, working modulo $4$,
$$2017^{2017}\equiv 1^{2017}\equiv 1\mod 4$$
Using this to find $2^{2017^{2017}}\mod 60$, we have
$$2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^5\equiv 32\mod 60$$
(Remember we need $k$ at least $2$ to use the remainder mod 4 in the exponent).  Putting it all together, we have 
$$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 32\cdot 7\equiv 44\mod 60$$

Comment: Your application of *Euler's theorem*  is wrong, because $14$ is not coprime to $60$.

Comment: There is something wrong with this argument. $14$ to any power greater than $1$ is divisible by $4.$ But that is not true of a number which is $14$ mod $60.$

Comment: @Bernard You're right! Fixing it now.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

Since $14\equiv 2\pmod 3$,

$$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^{2017^{2017}}\pmod 3.$$

Now, we know that the powers of $2$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
2^1=2&\equiv 2\pmod 3\\
2^2=4&\equiv 1\pmod 3\\
2^3=8&\equiv 2\pmod 3\\
2^4=16&\equiv 1\pmod 3\\
2^5=32&\equiv 2\pmod 3
\end{align*}
and so on.

In other words, since $2^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$, we only need to compute the power modulo $2$.  Since $2017^{2017}\equiv 1^{2017}\equiv 1\pmod 2$, we know that the power on $2$ is odd.  Hence
$$
14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^1\equiv 2\pmod 3.
$$

Comment: Yes you are right, done

Comment: You could've noted $14\equiv-1\mod 3$, and $2017^{2017}$ is obviously odd, making $$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv (-1)^{2017^{2017}}\equiv -1\equiv 2\mod 3$$

Comment: @vrugtehagel Certainly, but I was trying to give some insights into future questions where one might need to use the order of the element in the corresponding group.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you don't need to do the primes separately. 
$$\phi(60)=16$$
And $$2017\equiv 1\mod 16$$

So $$7^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 7\mod 60$$

Moreover $$2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2\mod 15$$ and $$2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 0\mod 4$$ thus we have

$$ 2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 32\mod 60$$ and

$$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 7\cdot 32\equiv 44\mod 60$$

Comment: Doesn't work, because $14$ is not a unit mod. $60$.

Comment: @Bernard Good point, let me think about that.

Comment: @Bernard Check out my revised answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $14$ to any power greater than one is divisible by $4.$ so this number is divisible by $4.$ On the other hand, $14 \equiv -1 \mod 15,$ and since $2017^{2017}$ is odd, the number is equal to $-1 \mod 15.$ So, the number is equal to $44 \mod 60.$

Answer (score 1):

Decompose $14^{2017^{2017}}=2^{2017^{2017}}7^{2017^{2017}} $.

Now, by *Euler's theorem*, as $7$ is coprime to $60$, $\,7^{\varphi(60)}=7^{16}\equiv 1\mod60$, so
$$7^{2017^{2017}}\equiv7^{2017^{2017}\bmod 16}\equiv7^{1^{2017}\bmod 16}\equiv7\mod60.$$
On the other hand, the successive powers of $2\bmod60$ follow a cycle of length $4$ for $n\ge 2$:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n&1&\color{blue}2&3&4&5&\color{blue}6&\dots\\
2^n&2&\color{red}4&8&16&32&\color{red}4&\dots
\end{array}$$
so that we have to find the value of $\bmod4$. This is easy: $2017\equiv 1\mod4$, so 
$$2^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 2^{1^{2017}}\equiv2^5\equiv32\mod 60$$
(don't forget the cycle begins at $n=2$).

Summing up these results, we obtain
$$14^{2017^{2017}}\equiv 32\cdot 7=224\equiv 44\mod60.$$

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion $2^{(1^{2017})}\equiv2^5$ mod $60$? I understand the successive powers results to $2^{4n+2}\equiv4 $ mod $60$ .